# SharePoint online in iframe of public facing site

Tags: sharepoint-online, public-website

I have developed the application in SharePoint online(Modern Team Site). My client want the sharepoint site to be rendered in Iframe of his public facing html website. So that users can login and see the website under his public facing website. I am not able to implement this as it throws "X-Frame-options" error. I understand this is something very rare requirement, specially when it comes to public facing site interaction with sharepoint. Does somebody have any solution to this problem.?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible.  MS set the X-Frame-Options header and the customer has no control over it.

Comment: Ohh Thanks for the assistance.